# Python3 - how to login to web form with hidden values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.4

I am trying to write a python script to login to the following site in order to automatically keep on eye on some of our merchant account details:

https://secure.worldpay.com/sso/public/auth/login.html?serviceIdentifier=merchantadmin

The credentials I am using are read-only, so cannot be used for anything nefarious, but something isn't quite working correctly.

My code so far:

```
import urllib
from requests import session

LOGIN_URL = "https://secure.worldpay.com/sso/public/auth/login.html?serviceIdentifier=merchantadmin"

_page = urllib.urlopen(LOGIN_URL)

_contents = _page.read()

_jlbz_index = _contents.find("jlbz")
_jlbz_start_index = _jlbz_index + 5
_jlbz_end_index = _jlbz_start_index + 41
jlbz = _contents[_jlbz_start_index:_jlbz_end_index]

fdt = _contents.find("formDisplayTime")
fdt_start_index = fdt + 23
fdt_end_index = fdt_start_index + 13
form_display_time = _contents[fdt_start_index:fdt_end_index]

fsh = _contents.find("formSubmitHash")
fsh_start_index = fsh + 22
fsh_end_index = fsh_start_index + 41
form_submit_hash = _contents[fsh_start_index:fsh_end_index]

post_auth_url = "https://secure-test.worldpay.com/merchant/common/start.html?jlbz={0}".format(jlbz)

payload = {
    "action": "j_security_check",
    "username": "USERNAME",
    "password": "PASSWORD",
    "jlbz": jlbz,
    "maiversion": "version1",
    "formDisplayTime": form_display_time,
    "formSubmitHash": form_submit_hash
}

with session() as c:
    c.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
    request = c.get(post_auth_url)
    print(request.headers)
    print(request.text)
```

I know it is currently a little long-winded but I find it easier to write a little verbosely when first trying something, and then refining later.

jlbz, formDisplayTime and formSubmitHash are all hidden input values from the page source - I am scraping this from the page, but obviously when I get to c.post, I'm opening the URL AGAIN, so these values are changing and are no longer valid?  However, I'm unsure how to rewrite the c.post line to ensure that I extract the correct hidden values for submission?

I don't think that this is only relevant to this site, but for any site with hidden random values?

Comment: Just a thing, they could be using your user-agent to hash with so requests and urllib have two different user-agents thus creating different hashes.

Plus as they have the formDisplayTime you should also try using a bit of sleep as they might be calculating how long you've been looking at it to scrape off dumb bots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user='xyzmohsin'
passwd='abcpasswd'

s=requests.Session()
headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"}
s.headers.update(headers)
r=s.get("https://secure.worldpay.com/sso/public/auth/login.html?serviceIdentifier=merchantadmin")
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
jlbz=soup.find("input",{"name":"jlbz"})['value']
maiversion=soup.find(id="maiversion")['value']
formDisplayTime=soup.find("input",{"name":"formDisplayTime"})['value']
formSubmitHash=soup.find("input",{"name":"formSubmitHash"})['value']

data={"jlbz":jlbz,
"username":user,
"password":passwd,
"maiversion":maiversion,
"formDisplayTime":formDisplayTime,
"formSubmitHash":formSubmitHash}

headers={"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Host":"secure.worldpay.com",
"Origin":"https://secure.worldpay.com",
"Referer":"https://secure.worldpay.com/sso/public/auth/login.html?serviceIdentifier=merchantadmin"}

login_url="https://secure.worldpay.com/sso/public/auth/j_security_check"

r=s.post(login_url,headers=headers,data=data)
```

I don't have the ID and password, hence I don't know which headers will work.
But if this doesn't work then please remove `Host, Origin and Referer` from the last `s.post` request's header

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: That worked wonders as soon as I put the correct credentials in and called the post_auth URL.  Many thanks!

Comment: thank you! Setting the headers with origin url and host values fixed the problem I was having (Apache tomcat "HTTP Status 408 - The time allowed for the login process has been exceeded.")